# Date changes while Inserting date into database using ajax processing (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using a CodeIgniter framework and uses jQuery and ajax to insert data from inputs. The problem is the date changes when I process it in ajax. Im using MySQL for the database and the data type is Date.

I've tried to change formats for the date because it might not be the same format.

Jquery/Ajax:

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#insertQL_form', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var month = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
      var nameCompany = $('#nameCompany').val();
      var email = $('#email').val();
      var position = $('#position').val();
      var ojLink = $('#ojLink').val();
      var remarks = $('#remarks').val();
      var withTestTask = $('#withTestTask').val();
      var testTaskStatus = $('#testTaskStatus').val();
      var withInterview = $('#withInterview').val();
      var overallStatus = $('#overallStatus').val();
      alert(month);
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'home/insertQL'?>",
        method:'POST',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);        
        }
      });
    });
```

Controller Function:

```
    public function insertQL()
    {
         if($_POST["action"] == "Add")
         {
            $insert_data = array(
                'month' =>  date("Y-m-d",$this->input->post('month')),
                'nameCompany' => $this->input->post('nameCompany'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'position' => $this->input->post('position'),
                'ojLink' => $this->input->post('ojLink'),
                'remarks' => $this->input->post('remarks'),
                'withTestTask' => $this->input->post('withTestTask'),
                'testTaskStatus' => $this->input->post('testTaskStatus'),
                'withInterview' => $this->input->post('withInterview'),
                'overallStatus' => $this->input->post('overallStatus')
            );
            $this->load->model('QLModel');
            $this->QLModel->insert_crud($insert_data);
            echo 'Data Inserted';
         }
    }
```

Comment: So what the `month` represents ?

Comment: its the date. misleading variable name.

Comment: Are not you getting any errors because you have mixed the JS and PHP code?

Comment: (I edited the code)I didn't get errors from these codes however the data that is being inserted in the 'month' variable is always 1970-01-01

Comment: Can paste the actual value of the `month` variable you get before changing the format.

Comment: @Migs what date output do you want to insert?

Answer (score 0):

`1970-01-01` this date MySQL stores when it not able to convert given date to the specific format of the date in MySQL that is `Year-month-day`, Use this code to fix that issue,

```
    function mformat_date($date_string)
    {
            // Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a 
            // slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is
            // assumed.

            return strtotime(implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $date_string))));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this before inserting to your db.

```
$m = strtr($this->input->post('month'), '/', '-');
```

then insert it like this.

```
'month' =>  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($m)),
```

Let me know the result.